# attempted relative import with no known parent package in anaconda(python 3.8.5) with vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3CSR.png)i am using anaconda(python 3.8.5)  in vscode
i am importing the y.py  to the x.py  by saying   # note : both my x and y are on the same folder named blog

the statement i used for importing is

from .x import func_name

but i am having issues with the relative import saying that:
ERROR:Exception has occurred: ImportError
attempted relative import with no known parent package
File "C:\Users\rbw19\bharathwajan\blog\x.py", line 2, in 
from .models import data

Answer (score 0):

In VSCode, when importing other files, VSCode searches for the imported file ("models.py") from the parent folder of the currently opened file ("views.py") by default, so we can use "`from models import data`":

[image]

The Python language service I use is `Jedi`.

```
"python.languageServer": "Jedi",
```

Comment: i can do as you say ,but my Django server stops by showing the error no module named models

Comment: @ Bharathwajan  -Have you tried reloading VSCode? Please provide us with detailed information about the problem you are currently experiencing.

Comment: @ Bharathwajan -How are things going? Please let us know if there is any progress.